# Problem with reducing/solving an equation

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I would like to know why this equation can't be solved, or reduced by *Mathematica*. (It's the same problem with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) )
I want to show that the Eigeinvalues of PHI are < 1 
Thank you.
[image]

```
> ClearAll["Global`*"];
a=3.5;b=4.4;e=3;m=1;gamma=1;k=1;
y=(MUY*T)/(1-Exp[e*r*(1-Exp[- gamma *T])/gamma - m*T]); (* y etoile *)
r=(MUR*T)/(1-Exp[- gamma * T]); (* r etoile *)
yp[t_]=y*Exp[e*r*(1-Exp[-gamma(t-k*T)])/gamma - m*(t-k*T)];
rp[t_]=r*Exp[-gamma(t-k*T)];
phi11[T_]= Exp[Integrate[a-b*yp[t],{t,0,T}]];
phi12[T_]=phi13[T_]=phi21[T_]=phi31[T_]=phi32[T_]=0;
phi22[T_]= Exp[Integrate[e*rp[t]-m,{t,0,T}]]
phi33[T_]= Exp[Integrate[-gamma,{t,0,T}]]
phi23[T_]=Exp[Integrate[e*yp[t],{t,0,T}]]
(*Reduce[{phi11[T]<1},MUY]*)
(*Reduce[{phi22[T]<1},MUR]*)

PHI= {{phi11[T],phi12[T],phi13[T]},{phi21[T],phi22[T],phi23[T]},{phi31[T],phi32[T],phi33[T]}};
MatrixForm[PHI]
Assuming[{T>0}, Reduce[{$Assumptions,Rationalize[-((1.4666666666666668` E^(-3 E^T MUR T) (-1.`+E^T) (-1.`+E^(3 E^T MUR T)) MUY)/((E^T-1.` E^(3 MUR T)) MUR))+3.5 T]< 0},{MUY}]]
(*Reduce[phi33[T]<1,T];*)
```

I would like to have `(phi11[T] <1 & phi22[T] <1 && phi33[T] < 1)` $\leftrightarrow$ (conditions on `MUY` and `MUR`)

Comment: Post code in code blocks rather than pictures of code. [`Markdown help`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Most methods either handle polynomials or perhaps transcendentals that are parameter-free.

Comment: I would like to have (phi11[T] <1 & phi22[T] <1 && phi33[T] < 1) <=> (conditions on MUY and MUR)

Comment: Simplify[Reduce[phi22[T]<1 && phi33[T]<1, {MUR,T}, Reals]]. But phi11[T]<1 seems more resistant.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't explain why `Reduce` has trouble with your eigenvalues, you can get explicit conditions on `MUR`, `MUY` and `T` for all your eigenvalues to be less than unity.

Obviously, `phi33[T] < 1` iff `T > 0`. For `phi22[T] < 1`:

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[PowerExpand[Log[phi22[T]]] < 0], T > 0]
```

[image]

Which gives you two sets of conditions to consider for `phi11[T]`.

Here's where it gets messy. Quite why, in the example you posted, `Reduce` doesn't see that `Log[phi11[T]]` is linear in `MUY` is a mystery. I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this (and I'll upvote it when someone else posts it, because I'm not seeing it).

To be precise, `phi11[T] < 1` iff

[image]

The `MUY` coefficient causes problems for `Reduce`, so you have to do some of the work yourself. Basically; take out the problem coefficient, replace it with `stuff`, do the reduction and simplifications, and then put it back in by replacing `stuff` with

```
stuffreplace = Coefficient[PowerExpand[Log[phi11[T]]], MUY]
```

[image]

(which is just the coefficient of `MUY`). Using this approach for the two cases that arose from `phi22[T] < 1` gives

```
cond1 = Simplify@(Reduce[(7 T)/2 + stuff MUY < 0 && T > 0 && 
      3 MUR < 1 && T + Log[3] < Log[1/MUR], MUY] /. stuff -> stuffreplace)

cond2 = Simplify@(Reduce[(7 T)/2 + stuff MUY < 0 && T > 0 && MUR <= 0, MUY] 
      /. stuff -> stuffreplace)
```

Both of these are a bit too long to post here, but they can be simplified dramatically. The simplification comes from subexpression

```
cond1[[3, 1, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

which, depending on other conditions, needs to be greater or less than zero to get `phi11 < 0`. Plotting this condition over `T` and `MUR`, with the red line indicating where the expression is zero:

```
Plot3D[E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) 
    (-1 + E^(3 E^T MUR T)) MUR, {MUR, -1.5, 1.5}, {T, 0, 1.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"MUR", "T"}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

Which looks suspiciously like a very nice way to change sign. Indeed

```
Solve[E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) (-1 + E^(3 E^T MUR T)) MUR == 0, 
  MUR, Reals]

(* {{MUR -> 0}, {MUR -> 1/3}} *)
```

At `MUR = 0` the expression doesn't actually change sign (first derivative zero, second derivative greater than zero for all `T`), so the sign only changes at `MUR = 1/3`. Then you can simplify `cond1` and `cond2` by replacing the inequality `E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) (-1 + E^(3 E^T MUR T)) MUR < (>) 0` with just `MUR > (<) 1 / 3`. (`Reduce` doesn't seem to be able to figure that one out, either.)

While you're at it, `Reduce` also has problems with the subexpression of `cond1`

```
cond1[[3, 1, 1, 2]]
```

[image]

but you can replace that with `stuff` again, as above.

```
cond1b = cond1 /. {E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) (-1 + E^(
       3 E^T MUR T)) MUR < 0 -> MUR > 1/3, 
  E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) (-1 + E^(
       3 E^T MUR T)) MUR > 0 -> MUR < 1/3, 
  (105 E^(3 E^T MUR T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) MUR T)/
       (44 (-1 + E^T) (-1 + E^(3 E^T MUR T))) -> stuff};

cond2b = cond2 /. {E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) (-1 + E^(
       3 E^T MUR T)) MUR < 0 -> MUR > 1/3, 
  E^(3 E^T MUR T) (-1 + E^T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) (-1 + E^(
       3 E^T MUR T)) MUR > 0 -> MUR < 1/3, 
  (105 E^(3 E^T MUR T) (E^T - E^(3 MUR T)) MUR T)/
       (44 (-1 + E^T) (-1 + E^(3 E^T MUR T))) -> stuff};
```

then `Reduce` and replace:

```
Reduce[cond1b, Reals] /. stuff -> cond1[[3, 1, 1, 2]]
Reduce[cond2b, Reals] /. stuff -> cond1[[3, 1, 1, 2]]
```

[image]
[image]

If either of these conditions are true, then all the eigenvalues will be less than 1.

You can look at these regions of `{T, MUR, MUY}` parameter space with `RegionPlot`:

```
GraphicsRow[{RegionPlot3D[
   cond1c, {MUY, 0, 2}, {T, 10^-7, 2}, {MUR, 0, 1/3}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"MUY", "T", "MUR"}, ViewPoint -> {-2, 2, 2}], 
  RegionPlot3D[cond2c, {MUR, -2, -10^-7}, {T, 10^-7, 2}, {MUY, 0, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"MUR", "T", "MUY"}, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, -2}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 750]
```

[image]

And you can check that the conditions are at least plausible by verifying the eigenvalues for points in or outside these regions. The function

```
validcheck[reg_, pt_] := 
   (RegionMember[reg, pt] && 
     (phi11[T] < 1 && phi22[T] < 1 && phi33[T] < 1 /. 
     {T -> pt[[1]], MUY -> pt[[2]], MUR -> pt[[3]]})) ||
   (! RegionMember[reg, pt] && 
     (phi11[T] >= 1 || phi22[T] >= 1 || phi33[T] >= 1 /. 
     {T -> pt[[1]], MUY -> pt[[2]], MUR -> pt[[3]]}))
```

returns `True` iff the point lies inside the region and the eigenvalues are all less than one, or the point lies outside the region and at least one of the eigenvalues are greater than one.

```
And @@ (validcheck[reg1, #] & /@ 
   RandomPoint[
    ImplicitRegion[True, {{T, 0, 2}, {MUY, 0, 2}, {MUR, 0, 1/3}}], 
    1000])
And @@ (validcheck[reg2, #] & /@ 
   RandomPoint[
    ImplicitRegion[True, {{T, 0, 2}, {MUY, 0, 2}, {MUR, -2, 0}}], 
    1000])


(* True
   True *)
```

(where, obviously, I've truncated the region limits because they're both in fact infinite).

Hope that gives you something you can use.